# Unable to assign decimal variable in Javascript [CRM Online 2016]

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I've got something puzzling me here and I don't have the experience behind me to spot the issue, so I ask your kind assistance.

I'm developing for CRM Online 2016 and I'm trying to extrapolate a value from another entity using oData.  I have managed to get the value of 0.2 from the source entity but when I try and assign this to a variable, the value 0.2 becomes 0.  See below:

Picture1:

[image: Image showing value contained in results.new_Rate]

Picture2:

[image: Image showing value assigned to variable]

I've only initialised the variables for testing purposes. How can I pass/use the value contained in results.new_Rate?  I'm looking to use this as a percentage in a Tax calculation.

Many Thanks

Comment: results.new_Rate in your first picture is a string, not a float, hence you will need to parse it. In your second picture, though, it seems to be a number (either an int or just a number), are you sure it is NOT related to the json response itself? any chance to get the original JSON answer? Besides, you can cast it as a number by just using parseFloat or just the unary operator (+) before results.new_Rate, like: `textRate = +results.new_Rate;` In either way, the json answer is the key here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried parseFloat(results.new_Rate); and parseFloat((results.new_Rate).toFixed(2)); and parseFloat(results.new_Rate).toFixed(2); but all return 0 in the variable. It's like .toFixed(2); isn't being called... This is the JSON string "{\r\n\"d\" : {\r\n\"new_Rate\": \"0.2000000000\"\r\n\}\r\n\}"

Comment: figured it.  the if statement was false....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your variable with this method:

`var taxRate = parseFloat((0.00).toFixed(2));`

The method "toFixed" keeps only two decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Jeez,

I found that the if statement was false and therefore not running the code.  Changed to:

```
if (results != null)
```

This now assigns the variable.

Now using parseFloat() and .toFixed(2); it works a treat.

Thank you for your suggestions